# wedge product of differential forms.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

When we speak of differential forms on a manifold $M$, we have two different visions. One is the point of view of sections of $\Lambda^rT^*M$, the other is of maps from $\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\cdots\times\mathfrak{X}(M)$ to $C^\infty(M)$.

In the first case, the wedge product between two differential forms is clear to me. ($p\in M$ and $X_1,\cdots,X_{r+s}\in T_pM$

$$(\alpha\wedge\beta)(p)(X_1,\cdots,X_r,X_{r+1},\cdots,X_{r+s}):=(\alpha(p)\wedge\beta(p))(X_1,\cdots,X_r,X_{r+1},\cdots,X_{r+s}) \\ = cst\sum_{\sigma\in S_{r+s}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\alpha(p)(X_1,\cdots,X_r)\beta(p)(X_{r+1},\cdots,X_{r+s})$$

But in the second case, is there a way of defining this wedge product directly? I would like to have a immediate definition for

$$(\alpha\wedge\beta)(X_1,\cdots,X_r,X_{r+1},\cdots,X_{r+s})$$

without having to pass through the other vision. Indeed, one could define it as follows:

$$(\alpha\wedge\beta)(X_1,\cdots,X_r,X_{r+1},\cdots,X_{r+s})(p) = (\alpha\wedge\beta)(p)(X_1(p),\cdots,X_r(p),X_{r+1}(p),\cdots,X_{r+s}(p))$$

But there is maybe a more direct way of defining this.

For example one could imagine

$$(\alpha\wedge\beta)(X_1,\cdots,X_r,X_{r+1},\cdots,X_{r+s}) := \alpha(X_1,\cdots,X_r)\wedge\beta(X_{r+1},\cdots,X_{r+s})$$

since the wedge of $C^\infty(M) = \Lambda^0T^*M$ is well defined.

Comment: You have a differential (r+s)-form. It means it is a totally antisymmetric tensor product of $\alpha ,\beta$. So you want to plug all the vectors $X$ into the forms in all combinatorics accounting for antisymmetry and sum them.

Comment: That is exactly what I have written. My question is what happens if you take the view that $\alpha\in\Omega^r(M),\beta\in\Omega^s(M)$ are seen as maps sending vector fields to $C^\infty$ maps on $M$.

Comment: So far there are two questions. "... is there a way of defining this wedge product directly" yes, via the tensor product. ".. what happens if you take the view that... are maps sending..." You can naively look at the forms as an object in Clifford algebra, duals to the multivectors. Or look at them as some small k-volume which you can integrate over a k-chain.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question should be easy. You understand the first definition, don't you? Then copy it to the second case: If $\alpha$ is a totally skew-symmetric map from $\mathfrak X(M) \times \cdots \times \mathfrak X(M)  \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ ($p$ times) and $\beta$ a totally skew-symmetric map from $\mathfrak X(M) \times \cdots \times \mathfrak X(M)  \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ ($q$ times), then you can define

$$
 \alpha\wedge\beta(X_1,\dots,X_p,X_{p+1},\dots,X_{p+q}) = \sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_{p+q}}\mbox{sgn }(\sigma) \alpha(X_{\sigma(1},\dots,X_{\sigma(p)}) \beta(X_{\sigma(p+1)},\dots,X_{\sigma(p+q)}) 
$$

In the above definition, you have constructed a totally skew map defined over $\mathfrak X(M) \times \cdots \times \mathfrak X(M)  \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ $p+q$ times and, as you wanted, you haven't use your first definition. I think that is your meaning of ''direct way''.

However, note that the final result of
$$
 \alpha\wedge\beta(X_1,\dots,X_p,X_{p+1},\dots,X_{p+q})
$$
is a function, and that a way to define a function is saying the value in each point of its domain, i.e.: instead of defining the function in terms of other functions (the right-hand term of my definition), you can define the product point-wise. Therefore you have been recovering your second definition (which you didn't like it a the begining by maybe now you do it).

I hope this answer helps you.